# Jquery Not Being Processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below Jquery does not run within my browser even though the syntax is correct( checked via online syntax checker) and the functions do run (tested with pure JS). Why is it that so?

I apologize in advance if the answer to this question is rather simple but after 15min of googling I could not arrive at an answer.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click', function( {
    closeLightBox()
});

function closeLightBox() {
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(1000);
}

function lightbox(x) {

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Lightbox </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightboxcss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "overlay"> </div> 


        <img src="batman.jpg" alt="" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="lightbox(1)" id="batman" style="height:100px;width:160px;margin-left:45%;margin-top:16%;">

        <br><br><br><br>

        <p> RANDOM TEXT STUFF </p><br><br>
        <p> 328ueekfuuirgh40t43h8hohro8ht </p>


   <script src="lightboxjs.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no link to jquery in your HTML. jQuery functions won't do anything you you don't link to the library.

Comment: It's not clear when you try to add the event listener--if it's before the HTML is rendered, it won't work.

Comment: When already using jQuery, why don't you use it for the event handler too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that javascript code is located in your .js file "lightboxjs.js". Did you include the jQuery library anywhere?

If you don't, start by adding this line `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` before including your custom javascript file.

Comment: The script you mentioned would go in the .html file before the script tags that mention my .js file correct?

Comment: You must order your js files in order of dependency. Thus if you are using code that depends on jquery then jquery should be loaded first else it won't work.

Comment: @Nahmed39 Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //page is ready

  $("#overlay").on("click",function(){
    this.fadeOut(1000);
  });
  });
```

You cannot add an eventlistener if the dom isnt loaded. Also dont forget to include jquery before executing the upper script
...

Comment: it should be `before the DOM is loaded`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling the jquery lib? You need to load the jquery just above lightboxjs.js and may as well use jquery syntax to listen to the #overlay click event.